# Will gate keeper allow two application with same identifier with different certificate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, code-signing, mac-app-store, osx-mountain-lion

I have two application with the same identifier.One is for mac app store and one is for other purpose (For distribution to outside of mac app store). And my both application are not exactly same, both has many difference in code and resources also. App store version of the app is signed by the "3rd Party Mac Developer Application:Company" and other one is signed by the "Developer ID Application:company".

My question is - will gate keeper allow my both application to run on 10.8 OS X? Thanks.

Update:  Since both application has different designated requirement but the same bundle, should it run.

Update: In my testing I found that both application's are running in my system and some other system. But in some system it allowing the mac app store application to launch but for non mac app store application it is showing one message that it gets damage and we should move it to trash. Why the same build's are showing the two different behavior in different system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Gatekeeper does allow it**. I have been able to run two apps sharing the same app ID, one from the App Store and the other standalone, on the same Mac. [1] However, **it is not recommended and can lead to other trouble**, because many things in the system specify applications by their supposedly unique ID. See for example [details on how Spaces works with respect to app IDs](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/236266-correct-way-to-identify-an-application-launch-services-spaces.html).

<sup>Actually, if you think of it, you actually do that every time you run a debugging version of a Mac app while also having the latest Mac App Store version stored in `/Applications`.</sup>